# Not able to select theme in experience editor

Tags: sxa

We are facing an issue while designing website using Experience Accelerator , in Experience editor that theme we created is not in theme selection box .

Comment: Can you update your question to include a screenshot of what you see?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create a site theme:

1) Add a new theme in one of the following ways:
Add a theme when creating your site. In the Create a new Experience Accelerator site dialog box, on the Theme tab, select the Create new theme checkbox.

The new theme is added to the Site folder in the Media Library:

```
/sitecore/Media Library/Project/Tenant Folder/Your Tenant/Your Site/Site Theme Name
```

2) Add a theme manually. Add a theme under your `tenant/site media library` folder. Copy all children of `/sitecore/media library/Themes/Basic theme`.

3) Add a theme using a script. SXA contains a helper script that creates a new theme for you. Right-click your site, click **Scripts**, and click **New Site Theme**.

In the **Create a new Experience Accelerator site theme** dialog box, enter a name and optionally enter a new location for your theme. By default, the new theme is added to: `/sitecore/Media Library/Project/Tenant Folder/Your Tenant/Your Site/Site Theme Name`.

> Note: By default, new themes are stored here: /sitecore/Media
>   Library/Project/Tenant Folder/Your Tenant/Your Site/Site Theme Name.
>   Do not save your theme items under any of the SXA roots as they might
>   be overwritten in the next release.

4) In the **Internet Explorer Compatibility** section, set the X-UA-Compatible value. This value forces Internet Explorer to use a specific Edit and Preview/Public mode to render your web pages. For example, you can set the value to **IE Edge** to use the highest, most recent mode available.

5) In the **Theme** section, set the themes your new theme should inherit from. SXA themes support multiple inheritance. This means that you can define multiple parent themes for every single theme.

> Note: The order of selected base themes is important. Be careful when
>   you are adding something new or changing the order. For example, if
>   the SearchTheme relies on jquery library that is located in Core
>   Libraries, you must make sure that the SearchTheme is loaded after the
>   other themes.

Sitecore [documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/designing/themes/add_a_theme)